# how to pass list of tags to anonymous function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, anonymous-function

This is my controller:

```
public JsonResult PostFunction(Post post,IEnumerable<int> MultipleTags)
    {
        post.PostedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        post.PostedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            foreach (var tagId in MultipleTags)
            {
                var tag = new Tag { TagId = tagId };
                db.Tags.Attach(tag); // this avoids duplicate tags
                post.Tags.Add(tag);
            }
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var usr = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == post.PostedBy);
                {
                Message = post.Message,
               // here, i am getting nothing but it should return back tagnames
                TagName = string.Join(",", post.Tags.Select(t => t.TagName)),
                PostedBy = post.PostedBy,
                PostedByName = post.ApplicationUser.UserName,
            };
            return Json( ret,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Howerever, data is properly got inserted into the database but this ret var is giving System.NullReferenceException. The line which is causing problem is TagName which should return comma seperated values.

If i Try something like this, then it works fine but it will not return the last inserted Post. means if in database, 7 posts are already there and after this new insertion, total no. of post are increased to 8 so it should return all 8 but it returns only 7 post excluding the latest one added.

```
   var ret = from data in db.Posts.Include(x=> x.Tags)
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.PostedDate).ToList()                  
                 select  new
                    {
                        TagName = string.Join(",", data.Tags.Select(t => t.TagName)),
```

**Now, how should i modify this anonymous function so that it should dynamically append the tags relating each post.**

Actually, there is a textbox with multi select drop down. all the values from text box and dropdown goes to this controller but after submit button, the latest submitted post should be added to the page. but this anonymous function is causing error.it should pass correct data to knockout binding but the code get stuck here.I am sure there is nothing to do with knockout here.

I have also tried to put a variable with all the selected tags and then assign it to TagName like this:

```
var result = post.Tags.SelectMany(e => e.TagName);
// and in ret var, 
TagName = string.Join(",", result)
```

but still getting NullReferenceException. 
Please suggest me what should i try here.

Comment: You have added a collection of new `Tag` to the `Post` but have only set the `TagId` property, not the `TagName` property so `post.Tags.Select(t => t.TagName)` wouldn't return any values.

Comment: okk, very good, tagId i have added to add back to database but i want back tagName so should i create a new variable and store tagname there and then access it, i have tried that but not get it done. if i am saying right, then how to do it. If i am wrong, then any other way to get back tagname @StephenMuecke

Comment: I have added at last in the question how i tried to put tagsname in a variable and then tried to pass to anonymous function, please have a look sir @StephenMuecke

Comment: Try to execute query and see result:
var result = post.Tags.SelectMany(e => e.TagName).ToList();

Comment: Your `PostFunction` method wouldn't even compile. Can you fix that?

Comment: @Enigmativity it compiles and give me result back if i remove tagName , i am having problem in returing back tagName

Comment: @neo - The code as posted in the question does **not** compile. The line `Message = post.Message,` would fail as it's not valid C# in this context. There appears to be code missing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value for TagName where you create the tag:

```
 foreach (var tagId in MultipleTags)
            {
                var tag = new Tag { TagId = tagId, TagName = "something" };
                db.Tags.Attach(tag); // this avoids duplicate tags
                post.Tags.Add(tag);
            }
```

Comment: TagName = db.Tags.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TagName.Where(x => x.TagId == tagId)) something like this should work but where method not giving TagId to select at this point (x => x.) what should i try, anything u want to suggest @jvanrhyn

Comment: What do you expect to see in the TagName?

Comment: in tagName, all the selected tags only, here tagId in for each loop is returning back only the ids of those tags and adding this back to post object. From this for each loop, many to many table linking Post and Tag is filled with PostId and TagId. Any extra needed plzz just ask me i know i have missed some code @jvanrhyn

Comment: Lets try this. Change this `var tag = new Tag { TagId = tagId  };` to this `var tag = new Tag { TagId = tagId, TagName = tagId.ToString() };` and see what happens